Is .NET AOT compilation supported on 64-bit ARM processors?
I will soon be starting a new .NET 8 project that will be deployed to systems running 64-bit ARM processors. The app will be a very basic CRUD program.
Before creating the project, I must describe the requirements and architecture for documentation purposes. Unfortunately, I cannot find a specific confirmation that .NET AOT is supported on these processors.

From the documentation: "The following table shows supported compilation targets." ... "Windows  x64, Arm64"

Yes. It also supports most platforms.

Yes, indeed. It supports multiple platforms, including Arm64. (3rd time the charm)

I've voted to reopen this question because the current closure reason, request for off-site resource recommendation, does not apply.

meta discussion, though imo this seems solved and appropriately closed (it directly asks for a reference for documentation, though that doesn't necessarily make it a bad question if it had some example(s), docs are wrong to answer with a workaround, etc.) .. really a try it and see approach, coming back with some errors or self-Answering with new knowledge would be most preferrable, but expecting users to invest in potentially useless hardware seems very steep https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430521/why-was-a-question-about-processor-support-for-net-aot-closed

@ti7, requests for official / canonical documentation are on-topic

@Chris certainly, but imo this Question suffers from a lack of specifics which is what that discusses - perhaps a MCVE to try on an arm64 system, what OS will be used, if some specific database software or driver is to be used which may not be available, JSON decoding, codpage 1252 awkwardness, etc., which would greatly improve it!

Yes, from the link provided by JonasH, at time of writing, the following are supported as native .NET 8 AOT compile targets



Platform
Supported architecture
Notes




Windows
x64, Arm64



Linux
x64, Arm64



macOS
x64, Arm64



iOS
Arm64
Experimental support


Android
x64, Arm64
Experimental, no built-in Java interoperability



Also note that they suffer from some serious limitations

No dynamic loading, for example, Assembly.LoadFile.
No run-time code generation, for example, System.Reflection.Emit.
No C++/CLI.
Windows: No built-in COM.
Requires trimming, which has limitations.
Implies compilation into a single file, which has known incompatibilities.
Applications include required runtime libraries (just like self-contained applications, increasing their size as compared to framework-dependent applications).
System.Linq.Expressions always use their interpreted form, which is slower than run-time generated compiled code.
Not all the runtime libraries are fully annotated to be native AOT compatible. That is, some warnings in the runtime libraries aren't actionable by end developers.

Content verbatim from and more details on Native AOT deployment.

Note that these limitations are for AOT in general, not just AOT on Arm
